# for ... in ... loop (Python) skips some values in list

Tags: python

I'm given a practice to write a function in Python that takes a list as input which includes all integers .
I should remove all odd numbers and let even numbers stay and return the list .

This is my function :

```
def purify (lst):
    for key in lst:
        if key % 2:
            lst.remove(key)
return lst
```

When I run it these are the results I get : (here are some test cases)

> print purify([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

results :

> 1
>   3
>   5
>   7
>   9
>   [2,4,6,8]

Another test case :
When I run using this line :

> print purify ([4,5,5,4,5,5])

results :

> 4
>   5
>   4
>   5
>   [4,4,5,5]

I'm not sure what's happening , if I remove that "if" condition , then there is no problem (like this):

```
def purify (lst):
    for key in lst:
        print key
return lst
```

It prints all values in list and doesn't skip any

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator % returns an integer value not a boolean, so when the return value is 0 it skips the statement.
Also you are modifiying the list you are iterating over, not good...

Try this:

```
def purify (lst):
    retLst = []
    for key in lst:
        if key % 2 == 0:
            lst.append(key)
    return retLst
```

Should work.

Comment: Errr.... But a non-zero value is a boolean True, and a zero (0) is a boolean False....

Comment: The boolean values True and False can be replaced with 1 and 0 respectively, meaning if True is the same as if 1

Comment: I am no Python programmer yet, but I'm pretty sure the solution is to make a copy of 'lst' BEFORE the for loop (and not just reference-copy)

Comment: Thanks ! I know the solution , BUT there is still something I can't understand ! "When the return value is 0 it skips the statement" and it becomes Zero IF AND ONLY IF the the list value is even (and odd) and that's exactly what I want . BUT my problem is it skips odd values too (although my if doesn't return 0) (it doesn't go over some odd values at all)

Comment: @ArdeshirIzadi, it is having strange behaviour becouse you are modifiying the list you are iterating over so you cant have knowlege about what the interpreter will do to deal with it, thats why I suggest creating another list and appending the correct values to it for return it later. It dosnt provide worst performance (not too much in this case) to create one more list.